# Push an identical array key next to it

Tags: php, arrays

The problem is like this...

An existing array:

```
Array(
    [0] => array('sample 1', 'sample 2')
    [1] => array('cat', 'dog')
)
```

Another array:

```
Array(
    [0] => array('sample 3', 'sample 4')
)
```

What I want to happen to add it next to 0 key so it became:

```
Array(
    [0] => array('sample 1', 'sample 2')
    [1] => array('sample 3', 'sample 4')
    [2] => array('cat', 'dog')
)
```

How do you do this?

@maxhud
I tried it but and the result is like this:

```
Array(
[0] => sample 1
[1] => sample 2
[2] => sample 3
[3] => sample 4
[4] => cat
[6] => dog
)
```

Here is my current current code snippet

```
$new_post_order = array();
foreach($the_query['posts'] as $the_post) {
$portfolio_reorder = '';
$portfolio_reorder = get_post_meta($the_post['ID'], 'portfolio_reorder', true); // Get the order on the db
if(empty($portfolio_reorder)) { // If its empty...
 $portfolio_reorder = 0; // Add default order                           
}
 array_splice($new_post_order, $portfolio_reorder, 0, $the_post);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $new_post_order );
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You accomplish this with `array_splice`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Example:

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, 3, 0, "purple");
// $input is now array("red", "green",
//          "blue", "purple", "yellow");
```

Give it a try yourself, and if you can't figure it out, make a comment and we'll help you out.

```
array_splice($new_post_order, $portfolio_reorder, 0, array($the_post));
```

Comment: Maxhud I have edited my question. Care look at my snippet. Thanks!

Comment: is a $the_post the equivalent of a 'sample' mentioned in your example? meaning, what does a $the_post variable store? Is it an array with two items, or a string?

Comment: $the_post variable is an array.

Comment: Can you include an example of one $the_post?

Comment: maxhud I will give you an approval on this since the snippet you gave seem to work. The problem I see is that it won't accept the default value key of 999 (from my snippet) but rather would start and accept from key 0. Not sure what's up with that... Anyway thanks!